# Finding maximum height of a falling object

Tags: kinematics

A champagne cork travels vertically into the air. It takes 4.0s to return to its starting
position.

a. How long does the cork take to reach its maximum height?

I assumed that the velocity at the maximum height to be 0 and trying to find the final velocity (returning to its starting position) with gravity = 9.8 and time = 4.0s. The final answer I got for final velocity is 4.0s, and I don't know what to do next, but I am not sure if my first step is right either. Please help. The final answer is 2.0 s.

Comment: Complicating this is the fact that a champagne cork is fairly light, so air resistance will be a significant factor.

Comment: @HotLicks This is clearly a school-level question about projectile motion. Somewhere in the question, it probably says _... neglecting air resistance.._. To the OP: the clue is _symmetry_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question seems to be very minimal, I think it's asking you about the physics concept of projectile motion. So I don't think it requires any calculation. You just need to remember that an object takes the same amount of time to rise to its peak as the amount of time it takes to travel from the peak to its original position. This means it takes 2.0s to reach the peak since the whole motion takes 4.0s.